# Concurrent Remote Data Processing

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, executorservice

I am writing a Java project in which a user can submit multiple queries at once and they are concurrently dispatched for processing on one of my servers.

To exemplify this, let's say a user enters several account numbers at once. The program should dispatch each one of these account numbers individually to my server and wait for the results of the processing. As each result is returned by the server, the program updates a Java Swing JList to show those results to the user.

So, let's say the user enters:

```
00001
00002
00003
00004
```

The program would then simultaneously dispatch 4 different requests to:

```
http://example.com/process_account.php?accountNumber=00001
http://example.com/process_account.php?accountNumber=00002
http://example.com/process_account.php?accountNumber=00003
http://example.com/process_account.php?accountNumber=00004
```

The results would then be displayed to the user in `jlist_AccountResults` as the server completes them. So the server may return: `43` to the account `00004` request; `12` to the account `00002` request; `36` to the account `00001` request; and `29` to the account `00003` request. As such, the output would be something like:

```
 Account 00004: 43
 Account 00002: 12
 Account 00001: 36
 Account 00003: 29
```

The key point here is that that the results are displayed as soon as they become available and processing is concurrent, not sequential.

Currently the program can sequentially process multiple queries, but when the list of queries is rather long, processing can take a very long time. Of course the total time to process grows as the number of queries grows, but if, for example, the program could process 4 queries at a time, it would drastically decrease the total time.

To handle this I have been looking into using either multithreading or an ExecutorService, but I would love to hear some alternative ideas. If anyone can supply examples or links to examples which handle similar problems, it would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: An executor *is* multithreading, except that it manages all of the hairy details and just lets you dispatch jobs to it. That's nearly always the way to go (although a larger framework, such as Spring, may additionally abstract some of the async logic for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecutorService` is multithreading and it seems like a right tool for the job. If you know the basics about threads and limit the communication between threads to minimum, this should be the simplest option. I would do something like this:

```
public static void get(URI[] uris) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    for (final URI uri : uris) {
        executor.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                InputStream input = uri.toURL().openStream();
                try {
                    Result result = readIntput(input);
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // notify UI
                        }
                    });
                } finally {
                    input.close();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Asynchronous IO is another option. For example: [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client). But it pretty much boils down to the same thing.

Comment: Great! Thank you for this answer. After looking into ExecutorService a little bit more, I agree that it should be the best option. That said, I will take a look at the AsyncHttpClient library. Thank you for bringing that library to my attention.